# How Can I Compute Line-by-Line Statistics Across Multiple Files in Python

Tags: python, scipy

I have a series of space-delimited data files in *x y* format as below for a dummy data set, where *y* represents independent sample population means for value *x*.

**File1.dat**

```
1 15.99
2 17.34
3 16.50
4 18.12
```

**File2.dat**

```
1 10.11
2 12.76
3 14.10
4 19.46
```

**File3.dat**

```
1 13.13
2 12.14
3 14.99
4 17.42
```

I am trying to compute the standard error of the mean (SEM) line-by-line to get an idea of the spread of the data for each value of *x*. As an example using the first line of each file (*x* = 1), a solution would first compute the SEM of sample population means `15.99`, `10.11`, and `13.13` and print the solution in format:

> x<sub>1</sub> SEM<sub>x1</sub>

...and so on, iterating for every line across the three files.

At the moment, I envisage a solution to be something along the lines of:

1. Read in the data using something like numpy, perhaps specifying only the line of interest for the current iteration. e.g.

   ```
   import numpy as np
   data1 = np.loadtxt('File1.dat')
   data2 = np.loadtxt('File2.dat')
   data3 = np.loadtxt('File3.dat')
   ```
2. Use a tool such as `Scipy` stats, calculate the SEM from the three sample population means extracted in step 1
3. Print result to stout
4. Repeat for remaining lines

While I imagine other stats packages such as `R` are well-suited to this task, I'd like to try and keep the solution solely contained within Python. I'm fairly new to the language, and I'm trying to get some practical knowledge in using it.

I see this as being a problem ideally suited for `Scipy` from what I've seen here in the forums, but haven't the vaguest idea where to start based upon the documentation.

*NB:* These files contain an equal number of lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First let's try to get just the columns of data that we need:

```
import numpy as np
filenames = map('File{}.dat'.format, range(1,4)) # ['File1.dat', ...]
data = map(np.loadtxt, filenames) # 3 arrays, each 4x2
stacked = np.vstack((arr[:,1] for arr in data))
```

Now we have just the data we need in a single array:

```
array([[ 15.99,  17.34,  16.5 ,  18.12],
       [ 10.11,  12.76,  14.1 ,  19.46],
       [ 13.13,  12.14,  14.99,  17.42]])
```

Next:

```
import scipy.stats as ss
result = ss.sem(stacked)
```

This gives you:

```
array([ 1.69761925,  1.63979674,  0.70048396,  0.59847956])
```

You can now print it, write it to a file (`np.savetxt`), etc.

---

Since you mentioned R, let's try that too!

```
filenames = c('File1.dat', 'File2.dat', 'File3.dat')
data = lapply(filenames, read.table)
stacked = cbind(data[[1]][2], data[[2]][2], data[[3]][2])
```

Now you have:

```
     V2    V2    V2
1 15.99 10.11 13.13
2 17.34 12.76 12.14
3 16.50 14.10 14.99
4 18.12 19.46 17.42
```

Finally:

```
apply(stacked, 1, sd) / sqrt(length(stacked))
```

Gives you:

```
1.6976192 1.6397967 0.7004840 0.5984796
```

This R solution is actually quite a bit worse in terms of performance, because it uses `apply` on all the rows to get the standard deviation (and `apply` is slow, because it invokes the target function once per row).  This is because base R does not offer row-wise (nor column-wise, etc.) standard deviation.  And I needed `sd` because base R does not offer SEM.  At least you can see it gives the same results.

Comment: Perfect! Really concise code. I haven't come across vstack before. Bonus points for offering a solution in R, too.